# Dividing using peano numbers in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to integrate an arithmetic function using peano numbers in Racket. I am only using recursion (no for / while loops)

Right now, I am working on division. I am not sure if I am in a correct path, but it seems like Racket is giving me a memory error. Here is what I have so far:

```
; Basic Peano axioms

(define (zero? n)
  (eq? n 'zero))

(define (nat? x)
  (cond
    [(zero? x) #t]
    [(pair? x) (and (eq? (first x) 'succ) (nat? (second x)))]
    [else #f]))

(define (succ n)
  (list 'succ n))

(define (pred n)
  (if (zero? n) 'zero (second n)))
```

```
; comparison of Peano numbers

(define (ltnat? m n)
  (cond
    [(zero? n) #f]
    [(zero? m) #t]
    [else (ltnat? (pred m) (pred n))]))

; Subtraction

(define (sub m n)
  (if (eq? m n)
      'zero
      (succ (sub (pred m) n)))
)

; Division

(define (div m n)
  (if (zero? m)
      'zero
      (if (eq? m n)
          '(succ zero)
          (if (ltnat? m n)
              'zero
              (succ (div (sub m n) n))))))
```

I've been trying to work on this for a quite long time, but had no luck. Basically, in division function, I am trying to write all base cases to end recursion, else do recursion.

I've also searched around on the internet, and nothing seems to fit what I am trying to do...

Any help/advice would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions of `sub` and `div` are incorrect. You should use `equal?` instead of `eq?` to compare Peano numbers.

This is because `eq?` tests for object *identity*: when two values are the *same* object, while `equal?` test for structural equality: for instance, when two lists have the same elements in the same order.

In this case, since you are comparing lists built with constructors in different parts of the program, even if they are structurally equal, they are different objects:

```
> (eq? 'zero 'zero) ; two constant symbols are made unique,
#t                  ; representing the same value in memory
> (eq? '(succ zero) '(succ zero)) ; two lists are read as
#f                                ; two different values
> (equal? '(succ zero) '(succ zero))
#t          ; the comparison here is done element by element
> (let ((a '(succ zero))) ; here we compare the same object
    (eq? a a))  ; the list is read only once and stored in memory
#t
```

So, for instance, instead of your definition of `sub`, you can use this definition:

```
(define (sub m n)
  (if (equal? m n)
      'zero
      (succ (sub (pred m) n)))
)
```

Note, however, that this definition falls in an infinite loop when the second argument is greater than the first argument. In fact, in the recursive call `m` is “decremented”, but it is never tested (in a base case) when it has become equal to zero. To avoid this, see the version discussed below.

Another important point is that `equal?`, because of its definition, in the case of lists performs a visit of both the lists, terminating when the first list end is found, which makes it a costly operator.

So, the previous definition of `sub` is also quite inefficient, since for each step of recursion the lists are visited. A much more efficient (and correct!) definition is the following, where the equality test is avoided and the recursion is handled correctly:

```
(define (sub m n)
  (cond
    [(zero? m) 'zero]
    [(zero? n) m]
    [else (sub (pred m) (pred n))]))
```

As a final note: also in the definition of `div`, when the divisor is `'zero` the function loops forever. This in a mathematical sense is correct since the division by zero is an indefinite operation. However, from a programming point of view, I think it would be more appropriate to return some kind of error.

Comment: ah, I see. Thank you so much! One quick question though: Why would `(eq? '(succ zero) '(succ zero))`
return false? I am assuming that both `'(succ zero)` have the same identity. Please let me know if i am wrong!

Comment: @IsaacSeo, I've update the answer. In practice the system reads two constant symbol and then manages them as a special case, making them unique (through an hash table), so they there are represented as the same value; instead, each constant list, when it is read, is not compared to other constant lists (too costly), and is stored in a new memory per se. So the two costants have two different addresses and are considered `equal` but not `eq`.